# Tag Synonym Request: [script] -> [scripts]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

The tag [scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/scripts) is just a pluralization of the tag [script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/script).

Also, I don't know if these should be synommized with the [shell-scripting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/shell-scripting) tag. I suppose there are scripts that aren't shell scripts, although it seems like all the questions with those two tags are about shell-scripting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. Thanks for your attention to detail.